# Comparing two objects to make a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have two object arrays.
What I want to do is:

1. Compare two objects
2. When key(name) and its value are the same, add that data to data_1
3. Make a 3rd object(data_3) with complete data.

Two objects I want to compare:

```
data_1 = [
           {name: "Mike", age: 30},
           {name: "Kelly", age: 25},
           {id: "A1", name: "Jack", age: 20}
         ]

data_2 = [
           {id: "A2", name: "Mike"},
           {id: "A3", name: "Kelly"}
         ]
```

New object with complete data:

```
data_3 = [
           {id: "A1", name: "Jack", age: 20}
           {id: "A2", name: "Mike", age: 30},
           {id: "A3", name: "Kelly", age: 25}}
         ]
```

I tried using `Array.prototype.forEach()` but it's not going well...:(

Comment: It would be easier if you changed one of the arrays to an object whose key is the name.

Comment: You question is bit contradicting. Based on the conditions you stated, how would you get this row `id: "A1", name: "Jack", age: 20` ? There is no matching key for this in the other array

Comment: I want to compare `name`. For example, there's `name: "Mike"` in data_1, and there's also `name: "Mike"` in data_2. So in this case, I want to take `{id: "A2", name: "Mike"}` from data_2 and add to `{name: "Mike", age: 30}` in data_1 to make `{id: "A2", name: "Mike", age: 30}`. Sorry I'm so new to this world...does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`, `some` and `find` like so, with destructuring to make it simple:

```js
const data_1 = [{
    name: "Mike",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: "Kelly",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    id: "A1",
    name: "Jack",
    age: 20
  }
];

const data_2 = [{
    id: "A2",
    name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    id: "A3",
    name: "Kelly"
  }
];

function combineArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  let result = arr1.map(obj => {
    if (obj.name && obj.age && obj.id) return obj;
    if (arr2.some(({ id, name }) => obj.name == name)) {
      let { id, name } = arr2.find(e => obj.name == e.name);
      return {
        id,
        name,
        age: obj.age
      };
    }
  });
  return result.sort((a, b) => +a.id[1] - +b.id[1]);
}

const data_3 = combineArrays(data_1, data_2);

console.log(data_3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very simple and clear...working exactly the way I wanted!!

Comment: No problem whatsoever @Kiki, I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can [**concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) both of the arrays and than [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) it based on names.

```js
let data_1 = [{name: "Mike", age: 30},{name: "Kelly", age: 25},{id: "A1", name: "Jack", age: 20}]
let data_2 = [{id: "A2", name: "Mike"},{id: "A3", name: "Kelly"}]

let merged = [...data_1,...data_2].reduce((op,{name,id,age}) => {
  if( op[name] ){
    op[name].id = id != undefined ? id : op[name].id
  } else {
    op[name] = {
      name,
      age,
      id: id!=undefined ? id : 'Not available'
    }
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Comment: I didn't think about `concat`...!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want more less code. You can use `lodash`

```js
data_1 = [{name: "Mike", age: 30},{name: "Kelly", age: 25},{id: "A1", name: "Jack", age: 20}]
data_2 = [{id: "A2", name: "Mike"},{id: "A3", name: "Kelly"}]

let d1 = _.keyBy(data_1, 'name')
let d2 = _.keyBy(data_2, 'name')
let rs = _.merge(d1, d2)
console.log(_.values(rs))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't know this library! The code looks so clean.. thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

```js
data_1 = [{
    name: "Mike",
    age: 30
  },
  {
   id:"A4",
    name: "Simon",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    id: "A1",
    name: "Jack",
    age: 20
  }
]

data_2 = [{
    id: "A2",
    name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    id: "A3",
    name: "Kelly"
  }
]
data_3 = [];
for (let i = 0, imax = data_1.length; i < imax; i++) {
  if (typeof data_2[i] != "undefined") { // this will check undefined index of different range
    if (typeof data_2[i].name != "undefined") { // this will check name attribute assume some times only get id and age prob if not remove this 
      if (data_1[i].name == data_2[i].name) { // this will compare 2 name if same merge it into 1 object
        let obj = extend(data_2[i], data_1[i]);
        data_3.push(obj) // then push to the array merged object
      }else{ // this else will push if name does not match but some id name bla bla..
      data_3.push(data_1[i]);
      }
    }
  } else { // this else will push if data_1 array longer than data_2 indexes values goes in here
    data_3.push(data_1[i]);
  }

}


// this function extend 2 object got
function extend(obj, src) {
  for (var key in src) {
    if (src.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = src[key];
  }
  return obj;
}
console.log(data_3)
```